# What is the reasoning behind `Date(epoch)` ignoring any parameter and returning the current time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Why** were the commands designed to have different outputs? Note how `Date(epoch)` yields the current time instead of parsing it. I stumbled upon this by accident and think it can introduce some nasty bugs if one is not aware of this.

```js
> Date(1596748882000)
'Tue Aug 11 2020 18:49:21 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)'
> new Date(1596748882000)
2020-08-06T21:21:22.000Z
```

Comment: Dupe does not explain why it reports a different date.

Comment: "Because spec" is a reasonable answer for me, but not satisfying. I reworded the question.

Comment: @sedot the usual answer for these things in JS is backwards compatibility, there probably was once a time when the Date object didn't exist and it was just the function